# May I add toolbar manually in UIWindows?

Tags: iphone, toolbar, uiwindow

I added UIWindow and its toolbar like:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1", @"test2", nil];
[[self.window rootViewController] setToolbarItems:arr animated:NO];
```

No toolbar showing up.

Is it doable? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show a sample code to demonstrate your solution. I am still stuck with it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your viewController (with a toolbar) to the window after the window's init.